# Can't get rid of icons with green locks on them

Tags: settings, lenovo

I would like to know how to get rid of these icons with the lock, every other app just goes but not these three. I used the small broom icon but these remained there and it didn't happen before. I'm using Android 4.2.2 in a Lenovo vibe x s960 smartphone.

[image: there are the icons with the green locks]

<sup>Click for larger version</sup>

Comment: Since the screen and icons you're interested in are specific to Lenovo phones, I've added the Lenovo tag to your answer, to help other Lenovo owners find it.

Comment: Flick them up one by one...

Comment: @DeerHunter what does that do? I've been trying to find an answer for the OP and I'm totally stumped. Nobody here has an LG sadly either. It's driving me a little (more) mad!

Comment: @RossC - the apps are removed from the memory.

Comment: @DeerHunter thanks! It's a weird function to have an Icon for an app that doesn't exist. Might be worth adding as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is the task bar showing applications currently in main memory. The broom cleans up main memory except "locked" apps. To clean them up, you can **flick them up one by one**.

Yet, **with Android it is not necessary to do this in the vast majority of cases**. Android OS does a pretty good job of managing memory and swapping apps to storage.

Answer (score 0):

Swipe the icons down to get rid of the lock, then swipe the icon up to get rid of the icon.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I can't say correctly but I think it's showing green lock because the application is locked by some other application, do you remember installing any application which may be responsible for locking those application off ! I would say you need to go through the application installed again. I think this must be some cleaner application which you may have installed recently.